# Why does negating $(\forall x\in R)(\exists y\in R\backslash ${0}$)(x^2=xy\Rightarrow x=y)$ change the set of alowed values for $y$

Tags: logic

Let statement $A$ be defined as $A=(\forall x\in R)(\exists y\in R\backslash ${0}$)(x^2=xy\Rightarrow x=y)$
If we now negate the statement, we get the following statement:
$(\exists x\in R)(\forall y\in R)(x^2=xy \land x\ne y)$ -source: textbook

Why did possible values of $y$ change from $R\backslash${0} to $R$ only?

Isn't that considered changing the definition of the original statement itself, not just negating it?
If we were to negate the negated statement, wouldn't we get the statement similar to the first one but without zero being excluded from considered values for $y$ which would mean that NOT (NOT A)$\ne$A?

Comment: $A$ is not a set; it is a sentence. And its negation is correct, but you have not to change the "restriction" on $y$ : it will be : $(\exists y \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \})$.

Comment: Yes, these are statements not sets, I corrected the question. I considered the negated statement above to be true since I found it in the textbook. So they made a mistake?

Comment: Maybe it is only a typo...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you say that *Why did possible values of $y$ change from $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbb R$ only?*

The negation of $A$ is

$$(\exists x\in \mathbb R)(\forall y\in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\})(x^2=xy \land x\ne y)$$

Comment: Since I found the example in the textbook, I considered it to be true. Apparently the best ones make mistakes too. Thank you for the reply!